# Issue automatically adjusting the height inside a Extjs 4.2.1 viewport

Tags: javascript, extjs, view

I have Viewport in an ExtJs app. When `rqstPanel` is collaped, `rsltsPanel` get activated. But it is not resizing.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
layout: 'border',
align: 'center',
border : 0,
defaultAlign : 'center',
items: [
{
    region: 'north',
    align: 'center',
    html : 'some html '
},
{
    region: 'center',
    align: 'center',
    minHeight: 500,
    items: [rqstPanel, rsltsPanel]
}
]
});
```

I have also tried :

```
Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
layout: 'border',
align: 'center',
border : 0,
defaultAlign : 'center',
items: [
{
    region: 'north',
    align: 'center',
    html : 'some html'
},
{
    region: 'center',
    align: 'center',
    minHeight: 500,
    items: [rqstPanel]
}
{
    region: 'south',
    align: 'center',
    minHeight: 500,
    items: [rsltPanel]
}
]
});
```

Comment: How do you "collapse" rqstPanel? What is the declaration of rqstPanel and rsltPanel? Why do you expect rsltsPanel to resize? There is no layout in the center panel. What item do you want to be resized? You need to provide a lot more details.

Comment: You might want to try promoting your subitems up to be your root layout panels.

Comment: @pcguru ​I collapse by calling the collapse method on the panel. Here is an example : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/dm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Thomas said, the example you link to works only because the the items are located in the viewport directly. The viewport is using `border layout`. Your rqstPanel is a subitem of a panel, and that panel is then in the border layout. So when the rqstpanel is collapsed it's parent, the panel, is not collapsed.

So the example has this hierarchy:

```
Viewport (layout: 'border')
 - Panel (north)
 - Panel (center)
 - Panel (south)
```

When fxp the center panel is collapsed, the layout of the viewport will resize the siblings to fill the available space.

You have this:

```
Viewport (layout: 'border')
 - Panel (north) with content 'some html'
 - Panel (center)
   - Panel rqstPanel
 - Panel (south)
   - Panel rsltPanel
```

This is due to the default xtype is 'panel' and you add rqstPanel as a child of that panel throught it's `items` configuration. This code here produces a panel that sits between the rqstPanel and the viewport.

```
{
    region: 'center',
    align: 'center',
    minHeight: 500,
    items: [rqstPanel]
}
```

So when rqstPanel is collapsed it's parent (center) is not resized by the viewport as all items it has (north/center/south) are of equal importance and wil take equal amount of height.

Basically what Thomas said will solve your problem. Don't let rqstPanel and rsltPanel be subitems of panels that are items in the viewport - add them directly as children.

basically what you want is to add your rqstPanel directly.

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.RequestPanel", {
    extend: "Ext.panel.Panel",
    alias: "widget.requestPanel",
    // other configs for this panel
});

Ext.define("MyApp.view.ResultsPanel", {
    extend: "Ext.panel.Panel",
    alias: "widget.resultsPanel",
    // other configs for this panel
});

Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border',
    align: 'center',
    border : 0,
    defaultAlign : 'center',
    items: [
        {
            region: 'north',
            align: 'center',
            html : 'some html'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'requestPanel',
            region: 'center',
            align: 'center',
            minHeight: 500
        },
        {
            xtype: 'resultsPanel',
            region: 'south',
            align: 'center',
            minHeight: 500
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: It really is a good answer. I cannot put all the code right inside the viewport. After we process the submit in the request panel I do this : `rqustPanel.ownerCt.collapse();` This​ ​seems to help, but the `rsltsPanel` still doesn't show the complete body.

Comment: Use `layout: fit` in the south panel. That will make rsltsPanel grow/shrink with it's parent. Currently you have no layout set which means the default value of auto is used, ie don't size the component based on parent at all.

Comment: ​layout: fit​ ​works perfectly. When I collapse first time th​e rslt​panel​ ​​fits ​nicely in the South panel region.

​But if I ​manually expand th​e​ rqstpanel th​e rslt​panel does not seem to fit the south region. 
Thank you for your help​.​